# error while counting a column and inner join another table

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join

i'm trying to count the most commented news. I have two tables: comments and news containing the same column: News_ID. here's the query

```
select *,count(News_ID) as count from comments inner join news where comments.News_ID = news.News_ID group by comments.News_ID order by count DESC limit 4
```

I get this error

```
#1052 - Column 'News_ID' in field list is ambiguous
```

Does it mean the column I'm trying to count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the name of table whose column you are using in select there are two `News_ID` column so in count its ambiguous for query to select which table's column,also use proper syntax for join with on clause

```
select n.*,c.*,count(n.News_ID) as count 
from comments c
inner join news n ON(c.News_ID = n.News_ID)
 group by c.News_ID 
order by count DESC limit 4
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you say what `news_id` you are getting in your select... `comments.news_id`, or `news.news_id`

```
select 
    *,
    count(comments.News_ID) as count 
from comments 
inner join news where comments.News_ID = news.News_ID 
group by comments.News_ID 
order by count DESC limit 4
```

Comment: of course.. i've done it before lol. if you have multiple columns called the same thing from different tables, you have to specify which one you want to pull out :)